# Replace phone number prefix mysql

Tags: mysql, prefix

I need to select and replace all Phone NO prefix (0122) with new number prefix (072) like

> 01220000000 to 0720000000

but my table has many format of Phone NO

> ('+11201220000000' , '+12201220000000@abc.com' or '01220000000/01220000001').

I tried to use REGEXP to find Phone NO have format like `^/0122/[0-9]{1,7}$`, but I have problem with

> 01220000000/01220000001.

How should I update all Phone NO by one query using Mysql

Comment: 01220000000/01220000001 an actual phone number? It looks like two concatenated phone numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track by using `REGEXP`.  Here is how I would phrase the update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET phone = REPLACE(CONCAT('072', SUBSTRING(phone, 5)), '/0122', '/072')
WHERE phone REGEXP '^[0+]122';
```

This answer should work assuming that, for the cases where two numbers appear, those numbers are always separated by forward slash *and* the first number would be a candidate for updating whenever the second number is also a candidate.

Note that your data is not normalized.  It isn't good database design to have fields containing more than one phone number.

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim Biegeleisen, sorry if what I said wasn't clear enough. Actually, I want to change the phone number '+1120122xxxxxxx' to '+112072xxxxxxx', '+0112' is just country code so i want to keep it.

Comment: Will _all_ of your numbers always have a leading `+112` country code?  If not, you can't really do this in MySQL.

Comment: Can i replace it by php then update to database? - @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: This is my new topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697114/replace-phone-prefix-of-multiple-format-using-php. @Tim Biegeleisen