# Replace phone prefix of multiple format using php

Tags: php, preg-replace, phone-number

I has an array :

```
    $phone_number = array ( 'phone' => '01219104579', 
    'phone' => '01219104579@abc.
    'phone' => '+8401219101219',
    'phone' => '01219104579/01219104479',
    'phone' => '841219104579@abc.com',
    'phone' => 'abcd01219104579@abc.com',
    'phone' => 'Hồ2101219104579@abc.com'
);
```

I need to replace all Phone NO prefix (0121 or 121) with new number prefix (072 or 72):

```
$phone_number = array ( 'phone' => '0729104579', 
'phone' => '0729104579@abc.com', 
'phone' => '+840729101219', 
'phone' => '0729104579/0729104479', 
'phone' => '84729104579@abc.com',
'phone' => 'abcd0729104579@abc.com',
'phone' => 'Hồ210729104579@abc.com' );
```

I tried to use PREG_REPLACE 
But i have problem with 8401219101219, number change to 84072910729. It should be 840729101219

How should I update all Phone NO using PHP

Comment: You said *prefix* so `8401219101219` hasn't `122` prefix that you trying to converting to `84072910729`!?

Comment: In fact, none of your numbers contain either `0122` or `122`. Also, where is your code to replace?

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want. I'm presuming you actually want to replace `0121` or `121` with `072` or `72` since that's what your sample data shows. If you really want to replace `122`, just change `121` to `122` in the regex below:

```
$phone_numbers = array ('01219104579', 
'01219104579@abc.com',
'+8401219101219',
'01219104579/01219104479',
'841219104579@abc.com'
);

foreach ($phone_numbers as $phone_number) {
    $new_numbers[] = preg_replace('/\b(\+?84?0?|0)121/', '${1}72', $phone_number);
}
print_r($new_numbers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0729104579
    [1] => 0729104579@abc.com
    [2] => +840729101219
    [3] => 0729104579/0729104479
    [4] => 84729104579@abc.com
)
```